# ZF2 as api module without zfcuser

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

I have a running ZF2 application with zfcUser used for authentication. In the application bootstrap the user is redirected to the login screen if not authenticated.
Now I want to add an Rest Api to the application which will be accessed via api.domain.tld I therefore created a new module with following routes:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'api.domain.local' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => ':3rd.:2nd.:1st',
                'contraints' => array(
                    '3rd' => 'api',
                    '2nd' => 'domain',
                    '1st' => '.*?', // is valid for .local and .com                    ),
                // Purposely omit default controller and action
                // to let the child routes control the route match
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(
                'index' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/index',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Rest\Controller\Index',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => TRUE,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

How to avoid the login screen when the api.domain.tld is called?

Comment: By configuring your `ZfcUser` to skip authentication for your rest module or by allowing guests (unauthenticated users) full access to that module.

Comment: exactly what I'm trying to do... I though to be able to check the route, speaking api.domain.tld, but this is not possible. Do I have to check it against $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]?